# Create product category and keyword search form in woocommerce?

Tags: categories, search, woocommerce-offtopic

i want to build category and keyword based search form. so i got this following form

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform_special" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/'  ) ); ?>">
                      <div>
                        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"><?php _e( 'Search for:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Search for products', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
                       <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php echo esc_attr__( 'Search' ); ?>" />
                       <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
                       <input type="hidden" id="home_url" value="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/'  ) ); ?>" />
                       <input type="hidden" id="categ_base_lang" value="<?php echo _x('product-category', 'slug', 'woocommerce') ?>" />
                      </div>
                    </form>
```

Its works only for keywords. When i update this to category search means not worked. my page screenshot is given below.

[image: My screenshot]

I want to make this type of header search. so please help me anyone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just made it for a client, you'll have to do it on the `pre_get_posts` action. That means you will add parameters to the WordPress query **before** it returns the posts.

Add this to functions.php:

```
// advanced search functionality
function advanced_search_query($query) {

    if($query->is_search()) {
        // category terms search.
        if (isset($_GET['category']) && !empty($_GET['category'])) {
            $query->set('tax_query', array(array(
                'taxonomy' => '***the_taxonomy_slug_of_your_category***',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array($_GET['category']) )
            ));
        }    
    }
    return $query;
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'advanced_search_query', 1000);
```

The code above works assuming you passed a `category` variable. You can do it by creating a `select` tag with 'category' as name :

```
<select name="category">
    <option value="***cat_slug***">Cat. name</option>
    <option value="***cat_slug***">Cat. name</option>
    <option value="***cat_slug***">Cat. name</option>
</select>
```

### The complete form:

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <!-- With this hidden input you can define a specific post type. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="your_post_type" />
    <input name="s" type="text" />
    <select name="category">
        <!-- Insert here all option tags you want, with category slug as value -->
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Once submitted, $_GET[] will contain `s`, `post_type` and `category`. `s` and `post_type` are used by default WP search, and `category` will be using in `pre_get_posts()` to add parameters to WP query.

So finally WP query will consider:

- **s :** your keywords.
- **post_type** : avoids mixing results if several post types have a same taxonomy.
- **category** : the taxonomy you're searching on.

### For WooCommerce

Replace the `action` attribute of your `<form>` tag by:

```
<?php echo get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ); ?>
```

You may also leave it empty if you're sure your form is only on the shop page.

Set the value of the hidden field to `product`, the custom post type slug for WC products.

Comment: i want to search product keyword also..

Comment: Yes of course.I'll edit my post to let you see the whole form!