# Woocommerce search form with category select

Tags: categories, search, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm tring to build an advanced search form for woocommerce based web site.

Found this answer (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/184186/51376) and added all codes. But it doesn't work.

functions.php

```
// advanced search functionality
function advanced_search_query($query) {

if($query->is_search()) {
    // category terms search.
    if (isset($_GET['product_cat']) && !empty($_GET['product_cat'])) {
        $query->set('tax_query', array(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'terms' => array($_GET['product_cat']) )
        ));
    }    
    return $query;
}
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'advanced_search_query', 1000);
```

search form;

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="woocommerce-product-search" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/'  ) ); ?>">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="search-form">
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="woocommerce-product-search-field"><?php _e( 'Search for:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <input type="search" id="woocommerce-product-search-field" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search Products&hellip;', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
    </div>
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'name=product_cat&hierarchical=1&taxonomy=product_cat&class=category-select&show_option_all=Tüm Kategoriler' ); ?>
    <div class="search-submit">
        <input type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
    </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code. Below code shows search box and woocommerce product categories . It will also show selected category.

```
   <form name="myform" method="GET" action="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>">

    <?php if (class_exists('WooCommerce')) : ?>
  <?php 
  if(isset($_REQUEST['product_cat']) && !empty($_REQUEST['product_cat']))
  {
   $optsetlect=$_REQUEST['product_cat'];
  }
 else{
  $optsetlect=0;  
  }
         $args = array(
                    'show_option_all' => esc_html__( 'All Categories', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'hierarchical' => 1,
                    'class' => 'cat',
                    'echo' => 1,
                    'value_field' => 'slug',
                    'selected' => $optsetlect
                );
          $args['taxonomy'] = 'product_cat';
          $args['name'] = 'product_cat';              
          $args['class'] = 'cate-dropdown hidden-xs';
          wp_dropdown_categories($args);

   ?>
  <input type="hidden" value="product" name="post_type">
<?php endif; ?>
               <input type="text"  name="s" class="searchbox" maxlength="128" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e('Search entire store here...', 'woocommerce'); ?>">

    <button type="submit" title="<?php esc_attr_e('Search', 'woocommerce'); ?>" class="search-btn-bg"><span><?php esc_attr_e('Search','woocommerce');?></span></button>
  </form>
```